# AWS Cognito custom attributes not being created

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

I am trying to setup a Cognito user using the AWS Cognito SDK and am having trouble adding custom attributes to a user. I have ensured that the variable names match up exactly and that the application allows read/write on all of the attributes.
My code looks like this:

```
var attributeList = [];

var dataName = {
    Name: 'name',
    Value: name
};
var dataPhoneNumber = {
    Name: 'phone_number',
    Value: phone
};
var dataIsDriver = {
    Name: 'custom:is_driver',
    Value: 0
};

var attributeName = new AWSCognito.CognitoIdentityServiceProvider.CognitoUserAttribute(dataName);
var attributePhoneNumber = new AWSCognito.CognitoIdentityServiceProvider.CognitoUserAttribute(dataPhoneNumber);
var attributeIsDriver = new AWSCognito.CognitoIdentityServiceProvider.CognitoUserAttribute(dataIsDriver);


attributeList.push(attributeName);
attributeList.push(attributePhoneNumber);
attributeList.push(attributeIsDriver);

var username = generateUUID();
localStorage.setItem("username", username);

var userPool = getUserPool();
userPool.signUp(username, password, attributeList, null, function (err, result) {
    if (err) {
        alert(err);
        return;
    }
}
```

With this code, the name and phone_number attributes are being set correctly but there is no "is_driver." I've tried to use adminGetUser to get **all** of the user's attributes but is_driver still doesn't appear. Any guidance would be appreciated!

Comment: What do you use for deploy? For example, I used serverless, and there is `authorizer` section, for example here described how to include custom attributes (also depends on proxy type) https://maketips.net/tip/175/include-custom-attributes-in-cognito-claims Also make sure you updated your token after including new attributes (they are stored in it)